# Initialization Time Out (Weighted Financial Data)

Tags: manipulate, data-structures

I've been playing with `WeightedData` and wanted a financial engineering example, a colleague suggested working with the fractional return (`FinancialData["Name","FractionalChange"`) of a weighted portfolio.

Things were going well until I tried to build a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
Grid[
{{Style[DateString[fractionalChanges[[1, day, 1]], {"DayName", " ", "Day", " ", 
   "MonthName", " ", "Year"}], "Text"], SpanFromLeft},
{Style["Unweighted Mean Fractional Change:", "Text"], 
Style[ToString@Mean[fractionalChanges[[All, day, 2]]], "Text"]},
{Style["Weighted Mean Fractional Change:", "Text"], 
Style[ToString@Mean[allWeightedFChanges[[day]]], "Text"]},
{Pane[
 Plot[{PDF[HistogramDistribution[allWeightedFChanges[[day]], 10], 
    x], PDF[HistogramDistribution[
     allWeightedFChanges[[day]]["InputData"], 10], x]}, {x, -0.03,
    0.03}, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  PlotLegends -> {"Weighted Fractional \nChange Distribution", 
    "Unweighted Fractional \nChange Distribution"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Fractional Change", " "}], {700, 280}, 
 ImageSizeAction -> "ResizeToFit", Alignment -> {Center, Center}],
 SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> All], {day, 1, 253, 1},
Initialization :> (thirtyRandomStocks = 
RandomChoice[FinancialData["FTSE100", "Members"], 30];
fractionalChanges = 
Chop@Map[FinancialData[#, "FractionalChange", DatePlus[-360]] &, 
  thirtyRandomStocks];
stockWeights = RandomInteger[{100, 10000}, 30];
allFChange = fractionalChanges[[All, All, 2]];
allWeightedFChanges = 
Table[WeightedData[allFChange[[All, i]], stockWeights], {i, 1, 
  Min[Table[
    Length[allFChange[[i, All]]], {i, 1, 
     Length[allFChange]}]]}];)]
```

I get an "Initialization Time Out" error and can't figure out how to give the `Manipulate` more time to initialise.

Therefore, I have two questions:

- How can I give Mathematica more time to initialise, or else ensure the `Manipulate` gets the necessary data for the calculations?
- Note: This `Manipulate` will always be used within notebooks, so Free CDF limitations aren't important for me at this point.
- Are there any suggestions you'd be willing to share to improve the code in general? I'm aware that if you look closely I'm not working with the data correctly; `allWeightedFChanges` doesn't really do what it should do.

Comment: First thing I'd do is to pay close attention to the reason of slow initialization. A quick guess is that this is due to `FinancialData`, so I'd start by caching it outside your `Manipulate` code if I were you.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I'd like to be able to use this Manipulate without having Initialization Cells if at all possible. Cormulion's answer below is probably the fastest way to do this.

Comment: Sure. Mu suggestion was anyway coming from general common sense and not necessarily taking into account your specific situation.

Comment: Understandable, I usually employ common sense when building things up and then it goes out the window when I attempt to dump everything within a `Manipulate`. `DynamicModule` would have provided me with more flexibility but I wanted a quick solution. Thanks again for commenting.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably better to heed Leonid's advice to re-configure, but, with `SynchronousInitialization -> False` added I got this after a while:

[image: graph]

Comment: Thanks @cormullion, I guess I just need to adjust my `DatePlus` value so that "a while" is "a little while".

Comment: I have the same problem because of using Manipulate in my code. As Cormullion pointed out, when add the "SynchronousInitialization -> False" into the code, Initialization Time Out error can be solved. If you don't mind, please help me explain. Thanks in advanced!